# Issue scrolling with fixed position

Tags: css, scroll, position, css-position

I am having trouble with the scrolling when I use a `position:fixed` inside of another `position:fixed`. The simplest way to demonstrate this issue is with this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xDDJb/

I want to be able to scroll with the mousewheel while having the mouse over the smaller fixed div. I have to keep `.wrapper` the way it is (aka I cannot remove the position:fixed).

The context is that I'm using Bootstrap 3 modals and I want to essentially create this layout in the modal. The BS `.modal` class uses `position: fixed` and creates the same construct as the example's `.wrapper`.

I would love any suggestions please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to use [jQuery Mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) to catch scroll events on your fixed div and then pass them through. Not elegant, but might do the trick.

Comment: Just managed to solve it. I'll post explanation once my 8 hour posting wait is over.

http://jsfiddle.net/PvKCK/1/

Comment: That works - the only problem might be that some of your content might be displayed in front of your `.box-fixed`. See jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PvKCK/2/)

Comment: hmmm youre right. Seems like I'll need to move to your suggestion.